# What to do with a highly-upvoted, old, hot mess of a question?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

This question showed up with an answer in the Late Answers review queue, and has almost everything wrong with it:

[Spring,Request method 'POST' not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699350/spring-request-method-post-not-supported)

The main reason why I'd expect this to be closed is that the problem OP describes is clearly caused by a typo in the word "professional", as described in the top-voted (but not accepted) answer.

The accepted answer can't possibly have solved the OP's problem.

The question itself isn't terrible, but the formatting and grammar are both *not great*, and the code that's included could be heavily reduced.

It's attracted a whole bunch of unrelated answers, most of which are unlikely to be helpful to people finding this question later.

However, it's highly up-voted - I suspect mostly because the title is a very generic error that could be the result of a huge number of different causes; this presumably also explains the broad range of answers. It seems to be the top hit on Google if you search for that error message.

It's also 5 years old and the user seems to have gone away.

My instinct is that it should be closed as it's really just noise, doesn't add anything particularly good to the site or the community at large, and if anything risks having a negative impact on SO's reputation when people find questions and answers like that at the top of Google.

On the other hand, clearly 22 people have disagreed with me, and you could argue that the broad range of answers increases the chance that someone with this generic error will find a solution that helps them, even if the cause of their problem is quite different from that which prompted the question 5 years ago.

What's the right thing to do with questions like this?

Comment: Considering it's a typo question, I've close-voted it as such. I suggest you do so too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A few comments

## Upvotes are not correlated with quality

I've seen answers with massive problems (i.e. SQL injection, security holes, etc) get upvotes. I've helped to close and delete more highly upvoted crap than I care to count. Maybe someone found it useful, or maybe someone was like "Ooh, [they have the same problem I do](https://xkcd.com/979/)". There's lots of people who want to reward others on SO, without considering if the question and/or answers are genuinely helpful.

## It's never too late to close old crap

Closure just means it doesn't measure up to community standards. In this case, we have a "Typo/Not Reproducible" closure reason, because typos are seldom helpful.

Comment: Also, any old post tends to accumulate up-votes over time, regardless of quality. Kind of a bandwagon effect. "Surely those 49 people up-voting before me can't have been wrong? I'll add the 50th up-vote".

Comment: I have the opposite problem: I try to upvote anything that has helped me, but if someone has gotten a lucky amount of points on one question, then their rep is no longer a measure of their quality as a community member. It's worth noting (just from observation) there are plenty of users with considerable rep who (still) have no idea how Stack Overflow works.